# MVCContrib Grid MVC 3 Razor .RowStart

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

Having trouble with the examples for the .RowStart method.

Comparing the 2 syntaxes: http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/03/01/mvccontrib-grid-part-5-the-action-syntax/

In this

```
.RowStart(row => string.Format("<tr{0}>", row.IsAlternate ? "style=\"background-color:#CCDDCC\"" : ""))
```

`row.IsAlternate` throws an error as row isnt the GridRow, its actually your model (well the row's data item).

The second syntax (ActionSyntax) :

```
.RowStart((p,row)  => {     
             if (row.IsAlternate) { %>
                   <tr style="background-color:#CCDDCC">
             <%  }  else  { %>
                 <tr>
             <% }
    }).Render(); %>
```

doesnt seem to translate to Razor

```
.RowStart((x, row) => string.Format("<tr class='{0}'>", row.IsAlternate ? "grid-row" : "grid-row-alt"))
```

Passes ok, but doesn't emit any row changes.

Any had this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just noticed some convention stuff that Html.Grid is putting in for you...

Given the Following

```
Html.Grid(Model.Results).Attributes(@class => "grid")
```

results in a table with class = "grid", 
even rows with a class = "gridrow", 
and odd rows with a class = "gridrow_alternate"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help but one thing I've been doing lately is using:

```
.RowAttributes(x => new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", x.value == myValue ? "highlight" : "" } })
```

This allows me to do a lot with css values for the attributes.  then for supporting "Zebra striping" I use pure css (browser compatibility could be an issue here, but it's graceful just doesn't render on old browsers) looks something like

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #eee;}
```

Gives u great control over the table. More info on the selectors [Sitepoint child selectors](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild)

Other wise you could try the [google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/mvccontrib-discuss?pli=1) for mvccontib Jeremy is usually sharp of the mark to help out.

Hope this helped.

Comment: its not wrong so +1, but alas css3 selectors will not work currently for the supported intranet browser.